# Ruby File IO Hang

Tags: ruby, file, io, freeze

The following Ruby code produces all of the expected output but does not exit properly. Before finishing the `each_byte` loop, it hangs - consuming 100% CPU - until the process is killed.

```
f = File.new(ARGV.shift)
i = 0
f.each_byte {printf("%08X\n", f.pos - 1) if (i += 1) % 16 == 1}
f.close
```

I've tried designing the loop in many different ways (replacing uses of `f.pos` with `i` or vice versa), and they all work fine! Only this one approach causes it to hang and I have no clue as to why.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok..since running the test code does not require any external ruby libraries I can compile 1.9 on my machine without installing it, and run the test program.

Here's what I see:

1. Ruby seems to "hang" (you can't interrupt it, and it doesn't exit by itself).
2. `top` shows ruby running at 100% CPU
3. `strace` shows no output once it goes into 100% CPU mode.

From this it's obvious Ruby goes into an infinite loop. And looking at `each_byte` in `io.c`, and adding a `printf` into the suspicious location reveals where we get stuck:

```
static VALUE
rb_io_each_byte(VALUE io)
{
    rb_io_t *fptr;
    char *p, *e;

    RETURN_ENUMERATOR(io, 0, 0);
    GetOpenFile(io, fptr);

    for (;;) {
        p = fptr->rbuf+fptr->rbuf_off;
        e = p + fptr->rbuf_len;

        printf("UH OH: %d < %d\n", p, e);  /* INFINITE LOOP ALERT */

        while (p < e) {
            fptr->rbuf_off++;
            fptr->rbuf_len--;
            rb_yield(INT2FIX(*p & 0xff));
            p++;
            errno = 0;
        }
        rb_io_check_byte_readable(fptr);
        READ_CHECK(fptr);
        if (io_fillbuf(fptr) < 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return io;
}
```

On my machine it prints this:

```
UH OH: 0 < 0
UH OH: 137343104 < 137351296
UH OH: 137343119 < 137343104
UH OH: 137343119 < 137343104
UH OH: 137343119 < 137343104
...ad infinitum...
```

And 137343119 is NOT less than 137343104, which means we stop going into the `while` loop (which would yield the block).

When you run the code so that it doesn't hang you get this:

```
UH OH: 0 < 0
UH OH: 137341560 < 137349752
UH OH: 137341560 < 137349752
UH OH: 137341560 < 137349752
UH OH: 137341560 < 137349752
....
```

And 137341560 IS less than 137349752.

Anyway..that's all I got for now. Still no clue why it's happening. But now we at least know WHAT is happening. Someone who wrote that code could probably explain why it's happening immidiately.

Anyway..I still think the `lseek` calls somehow mess up ruby's internal file pointers, and the above loop goes haywire because of that.

**EDIT**

And here's a fix:

Change `flush_before_seek` in `io.c` to look like this:

```
static rb_io_t *
flush_before_seek(rb_io_t *fptr)
{
  int wbuf_len = fptr->wbuf_len;

  if (io_fflush(fptr) < 0)
      rb_sys_fail(0);

    if (wbuf_len != 0)
      io_unread(fptr);

    errno = 0;
    return fptr;
}
```

What I added was the check for `wbuf_len != 0`, so that we don't do `io_unread` unnecessarily. Calling `io_unread` while in the `each_byte` loop is what messes things up. Skipping the unread makes things work and all the tests for `make test` still pass.

Anyway..it's not a proper fix, since there is some fundamental thought mistake with `f.pos`. It's just a workaround...but it fixes the above problem none the less :-/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to bet this is some kind of bug in Ruby 1.9.2 because it works fine in 1.8.7.

Hangs:

```
f.each_byte do
  i += 1
  if (i % 16 == 1)
    puts "%08X\n" % (f.pos - 1)
  end
end
```

Works without the `if`:

```
f.each_byte do
  i += 1
  # if (i % 16 == 1)
    puts "%08X\n" % (f.pos - 1)
  # end
end
```

Works with the `if` and without the `puts`:

```
f.each_byte do
  i += 1
  if (i % 16 == 1)
    # puts "%08X\n" % (f.pos - 1)
  end
end
```

Works with the `if` and the `puts` if there's another `puts`:

```
f.each_byte do
  i += 1
  if (i % 16 == 1)
    puts "%08X\n" % (f.pos - 1)
  end
  puts "%08X\n" % (f.pos - 1)
end
```

It also jams Ruby so badly it can't be interrupted, so that's usually a sign something internal is totally broken.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I get a hung process with `f.each_byte { if((i += 1) % 16 == 1) then puts f.pos - 1; else puts "foo!"; end }` so the extra `puts` needs to be outside the `if`.

Comment: But `f.each_byte { if((i += 1) % 16 == 1) then puts f.pos - 1; else puts f.pos - 1; end }` completes just fine.

Comment: What happens if you stop messing with f.pos inside the loop and just keep track of the position manually instead? I have a strange feeling that calling methods on f inside a block yielded on itself does something fishy to f causing the hang. Just a guess though..

Comment: Just looked at the Ruby source. Calling `pos` does all kinds of fun stuff, including `fflush`, and an `lseek`. Not sure how that plays with a loop that is reading bytes at the same time..

Comment: @Casper: `f.each_byte {puts "%08X\n" % (f.pos - 1) if f.pos % 16 == 1}` (which doesn't use `i` at all) does not hang either. There are many ways to restructure the loop such that `pos` is still called inside it and the script terminates correctly.

Comment: @Max @mu - Sorry guys I haven't got 1.9 installed, and I don't want to mess with my beautiful Ruby env (not even with rvm). However what I would do first if I HAD 1.9 was run `strace` on the version that locks up! That's going to pretty quickly tell you if it goes into some endless loop, or if there is something like an interpreter deadlock or similar. Anyone care to try and let's see what we get?

Comment: @Casper: Interesting. I ran a few different versions of the script with `strace`. They all start by `read`ing in the file, then they `_llseek` back to the beginning and start `_llseek`ing through again. The only obvious difference I can see is that the version that hangs seeks through in 16 byte increments, whereas the version I posted in my last comments seeks byte by byte.

I find this strange since, logically, both versions should be seeking in single byte increments. Perhaps Ruby is trying to simplify the loop and thus introducing the bug.

Comment: @Max - so the version that hangs..what does strace show when it hangs? Does the trace stop (i.e. no output) or does it continue indefinitely doing something (I'm trying to analyze the `io.c` code to see if I can spot where it would go into an infinite loop or something like that).